# Predict fitted Probabilities for gmnl regression

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models

I'm using the `gmnl` function to fit a mixed multinomial logit model. 
Since I'm further interested in the predicted probaliities of that model, I want to obtain them by applying something like the `predic` function.

```
 m4=gmnl(int_choice ~ 1+fico+annual_inc+int_emp_length+| time +grade+ last_fico |0, data = mldata, model="mixl",R=50,panel=TRUE,correlation = TRUE,ranp=c(annual_inc="n",int_emp_length="n"))

## how to mimic predict??
p_hat=predict(m4,type="probs")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a simple conversion rule like this:

- Convert a logit (glm output) to probability by computing exp() of the coefficients, which will give you the odds.
- Convert the odds into probability using this formula: `prob = odds / (1 + odds)`.

Very good explanation with examples can be found here: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/convert_logit2prob/

Comment: Very useful and I think for the multinomial logit mldel (MNL) this works fine. I'm a bit sceptic about using this solution with a mixed multinomial logit, since I want to also incluce the random variation for each subject. Maybe extracting the odd, and then adding rnorm() to the coeficients with random variation?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the best approach to adapt this rule to mixed models. You should try to ask this stats related questions on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The solution can't be found in the vignette but is documented in the help-file. Typing `help("fitted.gmnl")` yields the following:

```
fitted(object, outcome = TRUE, ...)
```

if TRUE, then the fitted and residuals methods return a vector that corresponds to the chosen alternative, otherwise it returns a matrix where each column corresponds to each alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I type str() over the gmnl model
I find an internal attribute called prob.alt that gives  choice - residuals
So in your case m4$prob.alt gives some usefull values, (find the max by row gives the predicted choice)

(In my case (a latent class mnl) this do not help since it has the predicted latent class probabilities)