# How to extract or predict latent class membership in gmnl?

Tags: r, multinomial

Let's say you run the example for a latent class model from `?gmnl`:

```
library(mlogit)
library(gmnl)

## Examples using the Electricity data set from the mlogit package
data("Electricity", package = "mlogit")
Electr <- mlogit.data(Electricity, id.var = "id", choice = "choice",
                      varying = 3:26, shape = "wide", sep = "")

## Estimate a LC model with 2 classes
Elec.lc <- gmnl(choice ~ pf + cl + loc + wk + tod + seas| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1,
                data = Electr,
                subset = 1:3000,
                model = 'lc',
                panel = TRUE,
                Q = 2)
summary(Elec.lc)
```

You get a fitted model with coefficient estimates for two classes (class 1 & 2). Is there a way to extract (or predict) for each observation, what the most likely class is that this observation belongs to?

After several helpful comments and lots of digging, it seems that there is an undocumented feature that allows you to get predicted class probabilities, which are stored in `Wnq`. You get one entry per observation and the number of columns matches the number of latent classes (`Q = 2` from above), and entries sum to `1`.

```
## Get class probabilities
head(Elec.lc$Wnq)
          init          
[1,] 0.5547805 0.4452195
[2,] 0.5547805 0.4452195
[3,] 0.5547805 0.4452195
[4,] 0.5547805 0.4452195
[5,] 0.5547805 0.4452195
[6,] 0.5547805 0.4452195
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but did you see this? OP didn't really get an answer though... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274727/predict-fitted-probabilities-for-gmnl-regression unsure if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

The fitted model contains a matrix called `prob.alt` which gives the probability of each choice, so you can do:

```r
predictions <- apply(Elec.cor$prob.alt,1,  which.max)

predictions
#>   [1] 1 1 2 3 1 4 4 3 3 3 2 1 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 1 1 4 1 1 4 4 4 2 4 3 1 2 4
#>  [38] 4 4 1 1 4 1 1 4 4 4 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 4 2 1 3 4 3 4 4
#>  [75] 4 1 4 2 3 2 2 1 3 3 4 3 4 1 1 4 2 1 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 4 3
#> [112] 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 1 1 4 2 1 4 4 2 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 4 3 2 2 2 2
#> [149] 1 4 2 2 2 1 2 1 4 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 4 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 1 4
#> [186] 2 2 2 2 4 2 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 4 2 1 4 4 3 2 2 4 4 1 3 4 1 2 4 3 1 1 1 2
#> [223] 3 4 4 4 1 2 4 2 3 4 4 1 3 4 2 3 3 2 4 1 1 4 4 4 2 1 3 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 4 4 2
#> [260] 4 3 2 1 2 4 2 3 3 4 1 3 4 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 1 3 2 3 1 3 3 1 4 2 1 4 4 2 2 1
#> [297] 3 1 1 4 2 4 1 2 4 1 1 4 4 4 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 1 1 1 2 3 1 4 4 3 4 3
#> [334] 2 1 1 4 1 1 4 4 2 2 1 3 1 3 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 3 4 3 2 2 2 2 1 4 3 2 2 2 1
#> [371] 2 4 4 1 3 4 2 3 3 2 1 3 3 3 3 4 1 1 4 1 1 4 4 2 2 2 4 2 3 4 4 4 1 4 2 3 2
#> [408] 1 4 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 4 3 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 1 2 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 1
#> [445] 1 4 1 1 4 4 4 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 3 4 3 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 4 2 4 3 3 3 4 1 1
#> [482] 4 2 1 4 4 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 2 2 4 2 3 4 4 4 3 4 2 3 2 2 4 2 3 4 4
#> [519] 1 1 4 2 3 2 2 4 1 1 4 4 4 2 2 3 1 3 2 1 2 2 1 4 4 2 2 2 4 2 1 4 3 2 2 2 4
#> [556] 2 1 1 4 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 4 3 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 2 4 4 4 3 4 2 3 3
#> [593] 3 1 3 3 1 1 2 3 1 4 4 3 4 3 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 3 3 4 1 3 4
#> [630] 2 3 3 2 3 1 1 4 4 4 2 2 3 1 3 1 1 2 3 1 4 4 3 3 3 4 1 4 4 4 3 4 1 4 3 1 1
#> [667] 3 3 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 4 4 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 4 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 4
#> [704] 1 2 2 2 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 1 4 3 2 2 2 4 2 1 4 2 2 2 2 4 2 1 3 4 3
#> [741] 1 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1
```

If we compare these predictions to the actual choice, we see that the prediction is correct about 50% of the time (the values in the diagonal are correct):

```r
table(predictions, Electricity$choice[1:750])
#>            
#> predictions   1   2   3   4
#>           1  78  35  28  32
#>           2  40 129  40  33
#>           3  16  27  57  24
#>           4  27  36  38 110
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks - yes, that gets at the predictions for the choices. But how can one get the predicted class weights w_iq?

Comment: Isn't that just the `prob.alt` columns 1:4?

Comment: Your comment sent me down the rabbit hole of looking at the source code of the gmnl() function itself and from there I was able to figure out that `Wnq` is what we are looking for. This release note confirms it, unfortunately it's not documented in the help text of gmnl.
`The predicted probabilities for each individual in each class are now accesibles through the element Wnq.` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmnl/news.html

Comment: The element Wnq is empty in the above example though

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. I fixed the code example which had a mistake in it. I added the solution up there as well. Thanks for the helpful discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this object `Wnq` is not class membership probabilities though.
Even in your example above, when calling `Elec.lc$Wnq`, you seem to have obtained a list of probabilities of class membership for your individuals, but critically **they are all equal across individuals**.
When looking for this  I also found myself with the same problem. I think `Elec.lc$Wnq` is just the mean of class membership probabilities.
I have not looked throughly in the gmnl code, but I think the object `Qir` is what you should look for ?